# Opening URL in new tab using XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, url, navigation

I have an xml document that holds the navigation structure for an swf file.  I need to have one of the URL's open in a new tab.  All of the urls are held in the xml file, the swf file references everything from the xml.

The link that I want to open in a new tab is the last one, "www.iwantthisinanewtab.com"

```
<item>
        <itemID>RESOURCES</itemID>
        <itemPageTitle>Resources</itemPageTitle>
        <itemPageURL>resources.html</itemPageURL>
        <submenuitemS active="true">
            <!--New SubMenu Item-->
            <submenuitem>
                <submenuitemID>OVERVIEW</submenuitemID>
                <submenuitemPageTitle>Resources</submenuitemPageTitle>
                <submenuitemPageURL>resources.html</submenuitemPageURL>
            </submenuitem>

            <!--New SubMenu Item-->
            <submenuitem>
                <submenuitemID>FLOWERS & GIFTS</submenuitemID>
                <submenuitemPageTitle>Flowers & Gifts</submenuitemPageTitle>
                <submenuitemPageURL>http://www.iwantthisinanewtab.com</submenuitemPageURL>
            </submenuitem>
```

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in AS use navigateToURL and its target parameter to set the URL target:
http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Using_navigateToURL_to_open_a_new_window__send_e_m-18770.html

for instance:

```
navigateToURL (new URLRequest ("mailto: blog@activetofocus.com"), "_blank");
```

In modern browsers it will open in a new tab.

I hope it helps,
Rob